# Blender to Unity vertexanimation for low poly battleships

Tags: animation, vertex-groups

I have programmed a mobile game in Unity, in which some low poly ships are visible simultaneously. The performance is good, but I would like to reduce the number of meshes and materials. Until now I have always animated the ships in Unity and separated towers, planes and other moving parts from the mesh. But now i would like to join the mesh completely in Blender and then animate it without bones/rigging, so that the performance in Unity is not affected by all the bones.

Is there a way to animate from Blender to Unity with a vertex animation? With AnimAll it is possible but relatively complicated. How would you normally proceed in this case? Rigging every single tower and ship is a waste of time, because the models are not supposed to deform organically, only the towers should rotate, ships should sink or airplanes should take off. Is it all too much effort for that little bit of performance that I get more out of it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't use Unity myself (UE4 here), but this sounds as if it could be solved by using NLA strips & shape keys in Blender. Have you looked into this?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Are shape keys not just for back and forth animations? For example, if I want to start a plane, all the curves and different rotations within the animation should cause problems, right? I know a little bit about actions, but the NLA Editor is just a tool to blend actions into each other, right?

Comment: So, am i right?

Comment: Not only for blending, also to "store" different animations (e.g. walk cycle, run cycle, idle loop, etc.) which can then be exported and played in the game engine

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for the answer! I'll try that.

Comment: Ok I've been studying it a bit now and it's really very handy if I don't want to create the same animations in Unity over and over again. I will use it in the future, thank you very much! 

However, as far as I can see, it doesn't solve the problem that I only want to use only one joined mesh. If I only have one mesh and want to record mesh animations with the NLA Editor, then this doesn't work right? Or am I missing something? If I google for it I can't find anything. This is probably only possible with bones, right?